# How can I write a test which gets the exact element I typed in the test?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

Here is how you can get an element which you type in a test in enzyme :

```
expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement( <img alt="img" src={'./name.jpg'}> ))
```

I was wondering How can I type this kind of test using react-testing-library ?

Comment: RTL uses some basic queries (https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet#queries) and allows for normal JS element queries. If you provide a more tangible testing example we could probably provide a more targeted answer.

Comment: @DrewReese I think this code that I found from the docs is helpful expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
  `)

Comment: @DrewReese But what I want to do is expect(..).toHaveElement('<h1>hey</h1>'); How can I do this with react-testing-library ?

Comment: RTL is a pretty significant paradigm & mindset shift from enzyme (it's quite literally the rejection of how enzyme tests react components), and I just want to warn that if you try to use RTL and write tests like you're using enzyme you will struggle. https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet#text-match-options Try something like `expect(queryByText('hey')).not.toBeNull()` or similar in whatever assertion library you use. Also, check out the [api-helpers](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-helpers).

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somehow nearly like the enzyme test

```
expect(screen.getByTestId('div')).toMatchInlineSnapshot(` <h1>Hello, World!</h1> `)
```